# Why isn't my rendered image appearing right?

Tags: rendering

I don't understand why I get this image result when i render through the render tab. It takes around 1 min to render and I get this image.

Image of render wanted (shot through the quick render):
[image]

Image of what image I got when i press F12 to render
[image]

My render tab settings (Only shows edited ones, all the rest settings are on default)

[image]

My Output tab settings (Intentionally left metadata cause its not necessary)

[image]

File:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/25xscax07eyfdzd/REFRESH.blend/file

I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Is the first image the camera view? Are you sure your camera is positioned right?
Or maybe there is an object set to invisible but still renderable in front of the camera?

Comment: You might be having a problem with clipping.

Comment: please provide blend file, so we don't have to guess but see what's going on

Comment: Yes, the first image is camera view, and about clipping i'm not sure given this is my first test render. But I'll be happy enough to provide blender file (Much Smarter Idea).

Comment: @AbielHailu You have an Object Called "WALL 3" is off for the viewport (Eye icon) but On for the render(Camera icon), delete that and that's it